# App crashes while entering background mode in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, background, crash

Today, I upgrade my Xcode to the latest version(Version 5.1 (5B130a)) to support iOS 7.1. After doing this, I run my project in Xcode as usually. Then app crashes while entering background mdoe. I didn't change any code before upgrading iOS SDK. The code is running perfectly in iOS 5.x, 6.x, 7.0.x.

When app is entering background mode, it doesn't do anything as the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // do nothing
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
```

After tracing the crash log, I found the crash point is on the highlighted line in the following screenshot:
[image]

any idea?

BTW, the project is using non-ARC mechanism. And view controllers are initialized by storyboard.

Comment: IS there a crash message on the debugger ?

Comment: it just goes main.m and show "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x62).

Comment: Does it always happen or just when you close the app on a particular view ?

Comment: What do you have in these ?

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: 100% happen while tap home key to make app entering background mode. not on a particular view, it happens on all view controllers.

Comment: Post your app del code ?

Comment: I don't do anything too in:

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   // do nothing
}

Comment: You're not using arc right ?

Comment: del code? do u mean dealloc function? but it doesn't run any dealloc function yet while app crashes. this is the dealloc function in AppDelegate.m. Simply release some view controllers and window variables.

- (void)dealloc {
 [_window release];
    [_activityView release];
    [_innerWebView release];
    [_cacheData release];
    [mailView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

Comment: No, I meant the code in your app delegate. You're also releasing Ivars in your dealloc. Put a break point in one of these. Based on your crash it looks like you're accessing a property that has already been released. Try enabling zombies too, this will tell you if this is happening.

Comment: The AppDelegate code are quite large and complex. Seems hardly to post it here... Orz. Zombies? It's my first time to hear that, I will try it to check. thanks! :)

Comment: Check my answer. Just the code from those methods form your app del.

Comment: oh my god! After I enable zombie objects. this problem doesn't happen any more! but if I disable it, then crashes problem happen again... what's happening.... ~"~

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are accessing something that has been released (guess based on your crash).

Enable zombies and this will tell you if you are and what the offending object is.

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

Then click on 'Run YOURPROJECT > Diagnostic > enable zombie objects

Then re-run and close it, see if the crash in the debuggers changes ...

Comment: oh my god! After I enable zombie objects. this problem doesn't happen any more! but if I disable it, then crashes problem happen again... what's happening.... ~"~

Comment: When an object retain count reaches 0 with zombies is enabled, the object doesn't get released. It's morphed into a NSZombie object. When this is then sent a message, your app won't crash but it will output a log warning you.

Comment: do you mean it will show up a warning message in console log? When entering background mode, I see nothing beside my own log message. @@

2014-03-14 17:06:02:323 AppGuru[3962:2315] TestFlight: Ending Session

Comment: What does the AppDelegate saveData method do ?

Comment: you can forget it, because I remove the saveData code just and try again. it still crashes while entering background mode. I remove TestFlight framework too, still crashes...

Comment: The problem is likely in your view controllers. Do they share any method calls ? ViewWillDissapear, ViewDidUnload (deprecated now) .. etc ?

Comment: If I enable zombies, it completely shows nothing in console log now while entering background mode. @@

Comment: share method calls? what do you mean? I didn't override the ViewWillDisappear and ViewDidUnload methods in my main view controller.

Comment: I meant do multiple view controllers do the same thing in these methods ? Oh so without zombie you don't get those logs in the app del ?

Comment: the problem is seems relative to my view controller code indeed. I mark all codes in main view controller just, and it won't crash any more while entering background mode. hmm... maybe I should check all functions in the view controller.

Comment: I am really appreciated for your help! Although the root cause is still existed, but I get the direction where to trace now. Thanks man!! :D

Comment: NO problems, check the code on your deallocs. I suspect it's an issue where you're releasing an ivar (_variable) and it's already been released. add a check i.e. if (_variable) [_variable release]; 
That way it will only release it if it isn't nil already... ? That are move it over to ARC ..

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the "Break point Navigator"
- left click on "Add a new Break point" at the bottom of the project navigator (left bottom)
- Click on "Add Exception Break point"

Now Run the project , you will get the exact point where you are getting the crash.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I know what happenes.

I get a table view controller like this:

```
@interface UserMenuViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    ....
}
```

in the following method, I create an UIButton component in the table view cell by using [UIButton buttonWithType:] methods. After inserting the button to cell, I release it. But I shouldn't do this, because it's a mistake. So, the UIButton object seems become chaos while app is going to enter background mode. After I marked the release code, it works fine now. ^^

But I still don't know why it is okay while running in iOS 5.x, 6.x and 7.0.x. It should crash too in those environments.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
....
if( row == 5 ) {
    BOOL bDidLogin = NO;
    NSString *fileName = bDidLogin? @"btn_logout.png":@"btn_login.png";
    SEL callback = bDidLogin? @selector(doLogout:):@selector(doLogin:);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
    UIButton *btn = [Utils generateImgButton:img withHandler:self withCallback:callback withBgColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    float x = cellWidth - btn.frame.size.width - padding*2;
    float y = cellHeight - btn.frame.size.height - padding*2;
    [Utils moveView:btn toX:x toY:y];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
    [btn release]; // should not do this!!!!!!!!!!!!!
}
....
}
```

in Utils.m:

```
+ (UIButton *) generateImgButton:(UIImage *)img withHandler:(id)handler withCallback:(SEL)callback
                 withBgColor:(UIColor *)bgColor {
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[button addTarget:handler action:callback forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return button;
 }
```